# choosing sim to send text message on a dual-sim sony xperia

Tags: android, sms, sony, smsmanager, dual-sim

It seems clear from several posts I read on this forum that the Android SDK  does not yet support dual-sim phones natively and that its up to the phone vendor to implement such support. I am using a Sony Experia M running Android 4.2.2 (Build 152.A.1.12) to develop a sms app. I was previously able to run this app successfully on a Nexus 4.  On the Experia however, the behavior is a little puzzling. SMSManager seems to always picks SIM 1 to send messages out. The default sms app on Experia gives a choice to the user to pick which SIM to use while sending messages.

I was wondering how to implement similar functionality in my app. Does Android natively enumerate the SIMs on the phone and if not has anyone been able to use the Sony SDK extensions to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The Sony Add-on SDK does not contain any support for dual SIM functionality.

Unfortunately at this time there are no public APIs available that support dual SIMs.

Comment: Thanks ! Is there any Sony specific way to enumerate the SIMs or use a specific SIM to send out a sms ?